# Java API to Split Oggs

Tags: java, audio, ogg

I'm looking for a Java API to split Ogg vorbis files.

JCraft seems good for playing oggs; seems like there should be a good way to utilize that to split them, but I don't see any documentation on the topic, and wouldn't really know where to start to accomplish that in JOrbis.

An all-java port of mp3splt would be most ideal.

Does anyone know of any such libraries?  Or maybe know how to leverage JOrbis to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: This question doesn’t appear to be about any specific programming problem. As such SO may not be the best platform for this question.